# How to access custom LOD for texture?

Tags: webgl

I have a 2x2 texture. I load LOD 0 (2x2 pixel array) and LOD 1 (1x1 pixel array). I then call `texture2D(tex, uv, lod)` in my fragment shader, but even when I specify 1.0 for the last parameter, I still get back pixel values from LOD 0.

In the example below, I would expect the triangle to be green, but it is red:

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 a_position;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = a_position;
  }
  `;
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  uniform sampler2D tex;
  float width = 400.0;
 
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, vec2(0.5, 0.5), 1.0);
  }
  `;

  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  const vShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vShader, vs);
  gl.compileShader(vShader);
  const fShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fShader, fs);
  gl.compileShader(fShader);
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  const success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (!success) {
    console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  }

  const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

  const pixels = [
    255, 0, 0, 255,
    255, 0, 0, 255,
    255, 0, 0, 255,
    255, 0, 0, 255,
  ];
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  // LOD 0
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 2, 2, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8ClampedArray(pixels));
  // LOD 1
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 1, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8ClampedArray([0, 255, 0, 255]));

  const positions = [
    -0.7, -0.5,
    0.7, -0.5,
    0, .5,
  ]

  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.lineWidth(50.0);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 3);
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For `bias` to work you need to actually enable mipmapping by [setting a respective texture filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texParameter) via the `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` and `TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` parameters. That being said, as far as I know it's not exactly specified how the `bias` parameter in `texture2D` actually affects the mip level calculation, so to get consistent results you'd want to use the [`EXT_shader_texture_lod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EXT_shader_texture_lod) extension and the accompanying `texture2DLod` function.